# Is the x in xmlns:x special?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I understand generally what `xmlns:x`means. What I don't completely understand is 'x'. Is this  namespace special or it's just a convention to use x to indicate a namespace with no particular meaning attached to it?

What I mean is we usually use 'x' as a variable representing some unknown. Let x be ...
Or for coordinates we use x and y. There's no particular meaning attached to x. Is this the same for x in `xmlns:x` ? Or does this `x` have some semantic origin?

Comment: The prefix `x` does not have any special meaning attached to it. It could have been `glorb` and it wouldn't have mattered (in theory). But as Michael Kay said, even though the prefix is supposed to be arbitrary, there may be cases when this principle is not followed (which is a bad thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a namespace prefix, a shorthand for the namespace URI. In theory you can use any prefix you like without changing the meaning of the document. However, some consumers of XML don't necessarily follow this principle, so check your processing pipeline before using an unconventional prefix.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I'll revised my question to make it clearer.